# How ferromagnet makes more sense than electromagnet in apple watch charging cable?

Tags: macbook-pro, charger, apple-watch

I don't see any use of ferromagnet in charging cable of apple watch or macbook (before 2017).
Why don't apple opt for electromagnet as it would only be magnetic when the charging code is powered. We would not even need a light indicator as cable would disconnect itself if power is removed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's [off-topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for the site.

Comment: Isn’t the forum supposed to answer hardware questions? Or is there anything else wrong with it?

Comment: Question regarding why and what Apple did encourages opinionated discussions are not under the purview of Ask Different.

Comment: But as I said, this question seems “opinionated” but it’s just a science question. Anyways, do what you think is right buddy.

Comment: Asking why Apple does something is off topic. Instead, please edit this to rephrase the question in the form “given that Apple has done X, how can I do Y” making a practical thing you wish to do can bring this sort of question on-topic for this site.

Comment: Hi Innocent Rock - Nimesh is correct. This isn’t a forum, it’s a narrowly scoped question and answer site with some guidelines on what’s on and off topic. See [help] and [tour] for details why this question has a hold placed on it.

Comment: Gotcha guys, edited the question.

Comment: This is an interesting *scientific* question, but not in anyway related to Apple.  It may be a good question in [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) or in [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).  That said, just a cursory look at things, I would venture a guess that the power requirements for an electromagnet of equal strength of a ferrous permanent magnet would outstrip the power capabilities of the USB port powering the device/charger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the size,

to obtain same magnetic force with Electromagnet as Permanent its size would not fit in to allowed space.

The other one would be unnecessary power consumption.

Finally, what is the benefit to the end user other then higher cost ?